# SELECTING from MySQL to OUTFILE is refused permission

Tags: permissions, mysql

I'm trying to export from a table to a csv file using:

```
SELECT ...etc...
INTO OUTFILE '/dump/denorm.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

(the query runs ok if leave out the `INTO OUTFILE...` lines so I know the SELECT query itself is not the problem)

I get this response:

```
Error Code: 1. Can't create/write to file '/dump/denorm.csv' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
```

The `--secure-file-priv` option is active but I successfully changed the allowed output folder to  `/dump/`. To check this, if I run this query: `SELECT @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv`
the response is that the secure folder is `/dump/`

I've checked the permissions on the `/dump` folder. ls returns this:

```
drwxrwxrwx   2 user sudo  4096 Nov 29 18:52 dump
```

Seeing as 'world' has been granted rwx permission to the dump folder, I'm not sure what is denying me permission to write the file. I'm running 16.04 and the latest version of MySQL

I'd be grateful for suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: The result of `ls`is trange.  Do you really have a group named `sudo`?  I would try at first to use a directory where you are sure to have access rights (your home directory, for instance `/home/username`)

Comment: It might connect to the user/group permission issue. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42794421/into-outfile-in-sql-on-mac-osx-errcode-13-permission-denied/50676747#50676747) states the same problem and there are some hints.

Comment: This link can solve this problem at least for me.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215231/load-data-infile-error-code-13